# Obtener un valor de un fieldset con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentado obtener los valores que un usuario escoja de un `fieldset` para después mostrar un `alert` que muestre el precio dependiendo de la opción escojida.

```js
function formAlertCompra(){
var year = fieldset.getElementById('año').value; 
var result_year=year*10;   
     alert(result_year);
     return false;
}
```

```html
<form ethod="post" onsubmit="formAlertCompra();"><fieldset data-role="fieldcontain" id="año"> 
    <label for="año">Año:</label>
    <select id="año_compra" name="año_compra">
     <option>Seleccione Uno</option>
     <option>2015</option>
     <option>2016</option>
     <option>2017</option>
     <option>2018</option>
    </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Register">   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Sin embargo al seleccionar el año no me esta saliendo ningun alert. Cual seria mi error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de empezar, vamos por unas observaciones generales:

1. El método se escribe como `method`, te hizo falta una "m".
2. En cada `onsubmit`, para evitar el comportamiento de envíar la petición hay varias maneras, siendo una de ellas el "retorno" de una variable como falsa.
3. Los `Fieldsets` carecen de valor definido, de acuerdo al contexto, lo que estás buscando es el valor que está dentro de las opciones mostradas, por lo tanto el valor requerido es del `select`.

El siguiente código soluciona tu problema.

```js
function formAlertCompra(){
var year = fieldset.getElementById("año_compra").value; 
var result_year=year*10;   
alert(result_year);
return false;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" onsubmit="return formAlertCompra();">
    <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain" id="año"> 
       <label for="año">Año:</label>
 <select id="año_compra" name="año_compra">
     <option>Seleccione Uno</option>
  <option>2015</option>
  <option>2016</option>
  <option>2017</option>
  <option>2018</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Register"> 
    </fieldset>
</form>
```